# Really need an excel VBA help on selection_change event

Tags: excel, vba

I have two sheets in my excel workbook. sheet A and B. Weekly we need to delete the sheet B and create a new sheet with the name B. currently we have a selectionchange event coded in sheet B. every time after deleting and re creating, we are re-coding sheet B with the same selection change event code.

Can we trigger a selectionchange event for sheet B from sheet A so that, when we delete the worksheet B, we don't have to code the worksheet B again with the selection_change event?

Answer (score 0):

Move your code to the `ThisWorkbook` module, and change to `Workbook_SheetSelectionChange` event.  This event is called by a selection change on any sheet in the workbook, so qualify the code with the required sheet name. `Sh` is a reference to the sheet the selection change occured on.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Sh.Name = "B" Then
        ' Your Sheet B SelectionChange event Code here
        '   make sure to qualify any worksheet references with Sh.
        '   eg Sh.Delete
    End If
End Sub
```